# Text document clustering using community detection algorithms

Tags: clustering, python, natural-language, social-network

I have a corpus of documents. I want to do clustering of similar documents by using community discovery algorithm. Initially I preprocessed the corpus by using nltk. Then each document is converted into a vector(BOW approach).

Now pairwise cosine-similarity of all the documents is taken as edge weight between two nodes (node here is a single document ). On this graph I want to apply some community detection algorithm. Can anyone help me out to choose the good community detection algorithm for doing clustering. Is this approach okay?

Comment: Community detection isn't that different from regular clustering. Which also often uses cosine matrices. Make sure you know the literature well enough, e.g., HAC, spectral, etc.

Comment: Actually Sir, here in this community detection method I want to do clustering based on the weighted graphs but in regular clustering algorithms we do on the data set itself. Like in Girvan Newman algorithm edge betweenness is the center point. So which community detection algorithm is fast enough to do the partitioning of graph??

Comment: And I studied clustering algorithms too but my project is on text document clustering by using community discovery algorithms.

Comment: Why go to the artificial "community" level in the first place? You have document similarities, not links here. Just cluster with a clustering algorithm, since most "community detection" works by clustering the nodes...

Comment: We need to go to community level because this is the work assigned to us by out prof.. Documents are taken as nodes and links between these nodes are created by using networkx library (Whole graph is created by using this library) . Where weights of the links are the cosine similarity between the nodes of that link. I want to work on this because may be this new algorithm will be having lesser time complexity and high accuracy compare to the traditional clustering approach.

Comment: I doubt that community detection has better time complexity. Can you even find a proven complexity in terms for a dense graph? Often the numbers you see rely on the graph being extremely sparse - O(1) edges - and that won't hold. Or the complexity is given in edges, not nodes. The. O(n log n) may sound good, buy it's actually O(n² log n), worse than most clustering algorithms... Louvain method for example looks much like hierarchical agglomerative clustering, so it can't be O(n log n) on dense data.

Comment: What the algorithms usually *do* is make better use of sparsity. A native implementation of HAC will make a O(n²) matrix that is mostly zeros on a spare network graph. But if your graph has O(n²) edges, these n benefits tend to disappear.

Comment: Complexity discussions in Barabasis network science book contain severe errors, unfortunately. Don't rely on them (ironically, he claims that hierarchical clustering is O(n²) when the presented algorithm is O(n³)...)

Comment: I am using Louvian method for dividing the network into communities . I want two clusters but Louvian method is giving clusters according to the highest modularity. Can u please tell me how can I get two only?...M using built-in community module on the graph